# [Unreal Engine 4.25]Visual studio 2019 can't understand c++ file( just added by editor)

Tags: unreal-engine4

Visual studio 2019 can't understand c++ file( just added by editor).
It is compiled well but VS2019 can't recognize its code block.
// After a long time VS2019 recognize its code block

This problem isn't critical but I'm very uncomfortable.
How can I resolve this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3MA5.png)

Comment: Visual Studio often has trouble parsing the intellisense for UE, I would recommend installing the UnrealVS plugin, and regenerating the project files.

Comment: @BenjaFriend thank you, but I already installed all plugins related with UE.
Every time it causes a problem, I'll regenerate the project files. :)